# OpenCV: найти углы поворота из матрицы поворота (SolvePnP)

Tags: opencv, матрицы

Использовал функцию `solvePnP` для определения координат объекта в СК камеры.

Сама функция `solvePnP` возвращает, помимо прочего, матрицу поворота 3x3. 
Можно ли как-то узнать углы поворота из этой матрицы? Похожие вопросы искал, но ответа не нашел. Не нашел также и то, как именно эта матрица устроена.

То есть, сам вид матрицы поворота может быть разным в зависимости от порядка поворотов (перемножения элементарных поворотов).

Спасибо.

Comment: Это так элементарно, что даже не знаю, что вам посоветовать. Прочтите для начала учебник линейной алгебры за первый курс любого вуза, это должно помочь. Также советую ознакомиться с работами таких авторов, как Буч, Танненбаум. Они смогут помочь приблизиться к ответу на Ваш вопрос

Comment: не может быть, чтобы искали и не нашли: вы либо врете, либо не сами не знаете что искали. Вот хотя бы википедия: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0

Comment: В этой ссылке представлена матрица элементарного (вдоль одной оси) поворота, а также матрица, заданная через углы Эйлера (которых существует не один набор, и непонятно какой из них мог использоваться в OpenCV). Смысл мне врать?